# How to change picturebox from visible to not visible if label with a certain number appears?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Good morning,

I'm creating a Stock software and I create two circles, one red and one yellow that I am using on a Picture box. I want that when the stock of label x is = or > 5 that picture box 1 appear on my dashboard. When label x is between 6 - 10 the yellow one appears and none of them appear if the value of label x is bigger than 10.

I tried to type different codes but none of them work correctly. 
My code right now is:

```
If StockDrillbits.GreenSquareQty.Text Or
   StockDrillbits.RedSquareQty.Text Or
   StockDrillbits.BlackSquareQty.Text Or 
   StockDrillbits.GreenStarQty.Text Or 
   StockDrillbits.RedStarQty.Text Or 
   StockDrillbits.BlackStarQty.Text = "5" Or "4" Or "3" Or "2" Or "1" Or "0" Then
    LowStockDrillbits.Visible = True
    MediumStockDrillbits.Visible = False
ElseIf StockDrillbits.GreenSquareQty.Text Or
       StockDrillbits.RedSquareQty.Text Or 
       StockDrillbits.BlackSquareQty.Text Or 
       StockDrillbits.GreenStarQty.Text Or 
       StockDrillbits.RedStarQty.Text Or 
       StockDrillbits.BlackStarQty.Text = "10" Or "9" Or "8" Or "7" Or "6" Then
    MediumStockDrillbits.Visible = True
    LowStockDrillbits.Visible = False
Else
    LowStockDrillbits.Visible = False
    MediumStockDrillbits.Visible = False
End If
```

I can't think any other way of doing this. I tried to convert any of the labels to int32, tried to create variables as integer and as single. Everything else on the software is working amazing but this simple code is not.

Anyone could help me? Code is Visual Basic.

Comment: You cannot say `variable = 5 or 4`.  Rather, you need to say `variable = 5 or variable = 4`, etc.

Comment: I tried, now I have a huge code for each label and the only picture box showing is the red one. Even if the label says 7, just the red one appears. I used at the end the else statement to make it not visible but it is still appearing the red dot too.

Comment: How is your progress? Is this problem solved now? I think the above replies can provide you with a solution, have you tried them?

Answer (score 1):

You have a common syntax mistake in your code.  While the `If` statement makes sense in English, you are thoroughly confusing VB.  As mentioned in my comment, you cannot say:

```
Text = "4" Or "5"
```

But instead you need to say:

```
Text = "4" Or Text = "5"
```

Applying this idea to your code, with a couple of enhancements, you end up with:

```
If Val(StockDrillbits.GreenSquareQty.Text) <= 5 Or Val(StockDrillbits.RedSquareQty.Text) <= 5 Or Val(StockDrillbits.BlackSquareQty.Text) <= 5 Or Val(StockDrillbits.GreenStarQty.Text) <= 5 Or Val(StockDrillbits.RedStarQty.Text) <= 5 Or Val(StockDrillbits.BlackStarQty.Text) <= 5 Then
   LowStockDrillbits.Visible = True
   MediumStockDrillbits.Visible = False
ElseIf Val(StockDrillbits.GreenSquareQty.Text) <= 10 Or Val(StockDrillbits.RedSquareQty.Text) <= 10 Or Val(StockDrillbits.BlackSquareQty.Text) <= 10 Or Val(StockDrillbits.GreenStarQty.Text) <= 10 Or Val(StockDrillbits.RedStarQty.Text) <= 10 Or Val(StockDrillbits.BlackStarQty.Text) <= 10 Then
   LowStockDrillbits.Visible = False
   MediumStockDrillbits.Visible = True
Else
   LowStockDrillbits.Visible = False
   MediumStockDrillbits.Visible = False
End If
```

I shortened the code somewhat by using `<=` instead of a hard-coded range of numbers.  Also, I applied `Val` to the Text so you are actually comparing numbers instead of strings.  If you like, `Val` can be replaced with, for instance, `CType`.

Comment: It's still happening. Used the code provided but the software just shows the red dot. I took print screens, but I can't upload them here :/

Comment: I just noticed this is tagged vb.net, not vb6, but the same idea applies.

Comment: You have 6 text boxes.  Do they all need to fall into the same range of numbers for the red or yellow graphic to appear?  The way it's coded now, if ANY textbox <= 5 the red graphic will appear.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a developer, that's why I don't know why it's not working, even with the code provided is not working. would I have to change anything being vb.net?

Comment: The syntax is fine.  More important is an answer to my second comment.

Comment: I have a third form with 6 textboxes. This textboxes allow me to update the value of the label on form two. My dashboard is form one and I want to that if any of the 6 labels on form 2 is less or equal to 10, then the yellow circle will show on my dashboard. If is equal or less than 5 (any of the labels), it needs to show the red dot on the dashboard. Right now, the red dot appears because when I start the application, all labels are = 0, so because there's no stock, the red dot appears on the dashboard. After I update the stock in any or all labels, the red dot does not change to yellow or

Comment: ... not visible.

Comment: Where is this code located?  And where is this code being called from?  It sounds like when form 3 closes, or you press a button on form 3, you need to update form 1 by running the logic in this answer.

Comment: I'm writing the code on Dashboard_Load because I want the red and yellow circle being shown on the dashboard form. About the labels, the quantity is ok, no problems so far. I can close the form and open it again and the correct quantity remains there.

Comment: Which means this code is only running once.  You need it to run other times, too.  Since I don't know your app, I can only speculate when this needs to happen, but some obvious times might be when form 3 is closed, or a button is pressed on form 3, etc.  However you signify the changes need to be applied.

Comment: Form 3 just allow me to update the quantity, there's no labels. From form 2 I'm calling the quantity that I insert on the textbox on form 3 and it saves the value on form 2, so I won't be using form 3 all the time. So, even if I close the app, form 2 will keep giving me the right quantity. I don't understand why on form 1 is not working if the quantity remains the same most of the time. I don't know where else I could put the code on because form 2 is working fine.

Comment: How could I make it run multiple times?

Comment: If you move the code into a Public Sub, then the code can be called from Dashboard_Load and wherever else is necessary.  But without knowing your app, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: This is way harder than I thought would be. I'm probably give up. Makes me sad, I really wanted to make this happen.

Answer (score 1):

Add the values to be compared to arrays, this makes the comparison code more compact.

```
Dim lowLables As String() = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}
Dim highLables As String() = {"6", "7", "8", "9", "10"}
Dim quantities As String() = {
    StockDrillbits.GreenSquareQty.Text,
    StockDrillbits.RedSquareQty.Text,
    StockDrillbits.BlackSquareQty.Text,
    StockDrillbits.GreenStarQty.Text,
    StockDrillbits.RedStarQty.Text,
    StockDrillbits.BlackStarQty.Text }

LowStockDrillbits.Visible = quantities.Any(Function(q) lowLables.Contains(q)) 
MediumStockDrillbits.Visible = quantities.Any(Function(q) highLables.Contains(q))
```

My code uses LINQ Method Syntax. First, it creates 2 arrays containig the labels "0" to "5" and "6" to "10". Then it creates an array named `quantities` containing the text of the `StockDrillbits` textboxes or labels.

`quantities.Any(...)` contains a condition that must be `True` for any of the quantity strings. The condition is given as a [Lambda Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/lambda-expressions). The condition lambda `Function(q) lowLables.Contains(q)` tests whether a quantity string is contained in the `lowLables` array. The same is then done for the `highLables` array.

I also replaced the lengthy If-statement by direct assignment of the condition results to the picture boxes.

Comment: It's still just appearing the red dot with this code. I'm so lost right now! Nothing is working...

Comment: You need an `Imports System.Linq` at the top of the code.